# try to run video from youtube using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I make code below start video from youtube automatically?

This code is work for image how can i make it work for video for code section below

```
var img2 = document.createElement('img');
img2.src = "http://www.mykohsamui.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/sunset-samara-samui.jpg";
infowincontent.appendChild(img2);
```

My code for video:

```
var img2 = document.createElement('video');
img2.src = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BGCpKQTMfo";
img2.autoPlay = true;
infowincontent.appendChild(img2);
```

Comment: You can't just feed a YouTube URL to a `video` element like that. Media elements expect links to files, not web pages. Why don't you use the YouTube player and embed?

Comment: @AOLNathon Refer [JSFiddle youtube video player](http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/e11oy0eu/)

Comment: var link='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BGCpKQTMfo';
              link=link.replace('watch?v=','embed/');
              var img2 = document.createElement('iframe');
              img2.src = link;
              img2.autoPlay = true;
              img2.style.width='250px';
              img2.style.height='200px';
              infowincontent.appendChild(img2);

Comment: I try this one it's work but It not auto play I still need to click then video will run